# Android studio Gradle sync issue

Tags: android

Can anybody help with this issue, When i start android studio latest after having been started it states following
"The project encoding (Windows-1252) does not match the encoding specified in the Gradle build files (UTF-8). This can lead to serious bugs.please help how to solve this?"
Please advise how to solve this if anybody knows.

Answer (score 1):

Just click on the link that appears below the error message and change all the drop-down menus to UTF-8. That'll fix the problem.